# How to evaluate empty quosure programmatically?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

In my dataset, I have a few possible grouping variables a, b, c. How do I programmatically tell dplyr to not group by any variables?

For example:

```
granularity <- NA

if(isTRUE(granularity == 'all')){
  # all group variables
  group_variables <- quos(a, b, c)

}else if(isTRUE(granularity == 'no_c')){
  # all except c
  group_variables <- quos(a, b)

}else{
  # no group variables
  group_variables <- quo()
}

data_summary <- mydata %>%
  group_by(!!! group_variables) %>%
  summarise(
    x_mean = mean(x)
  )
```

This will run correctly if I set granularity to 'all' or 'no_c', but it fails when I assign group_variables to the empty quosure. Does anyone know how to make this work?

Edit: This question also applies to functions like select, so assume I wanted to run

```
data_select <- mydata %>%
  select(!!! select_variables, d, e, f)
```

How do I set select_variables to sometimes be quos(a, b, c) or sometimes be empty?

Thanks!

Comment: Hey I just added an edit. Even if we use something like `select`, even when it has extra arguments that could execute even if `select_variables` is empty, it still throws an error.

Comment: @RLave wrong - `foo %>% group_by() %>% summarize(....)` works as expected - treating the data as one group.

Comment: What about using `rlang::quo_is_missing(group_variables)` as a condition to include or not `group_by`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `group_variables <- NULL` in that clause:

```
}else{
                                    # no group variables
    group_variables <- NULL
}
```

also note the massive warning:

```
Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) : 
  Column `<empty>` is unknown
In addition: Warning message:
Unquoting language objects with `!!!` is soft-deprecated as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `!!` instead.

  # Bad:
  dplyr::select(data, !!!enquo(x))

  # Good:
  dplyr::select(data, !!enquo(x))    # Unquote single quosure
  dplyr::select(data, !!!enquos(x))  # Splice list of quosures
```

You might want to consider not using packages with unstable APIs.

Comment: Ah sorry wasn't getting that warning, updated and getting it now.